# iOS HTTP Post won't run url

Tags: ios, http-post

I'm performing a HTTP Post in iOS, and using it to run an insert via php on a database. I have a somewhat lengthy form for giving it values to insert, and I pull them all together into a single string, which I include in my method to run the url(right now it's a GET, I've tried it with POST for similar results), and when I test it out, it won't run. I can copy the url it creates and paste that into a browser and run it that way, but it won't run through the iOS application.

I've also tried with ASIHTTPRequest, with no results either way.

Here is my HTTP Post method:

```
NSString *content = @"";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:inserturl1]];
NSLog(inserturl1);
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *results = [returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<br />"];
NSLog([results objectAtIndex:0]);
```

and here is the building of the URL:

```
NSString *fn = [firstname text]; // First Name, fn from insert url
    NSString *ln = [lastname text]; // Last Name, ln from url
    NSString *age = [ageLabel text];
    NSString *als = [address text]; // Address last seen, als from insert url
    NSString *cls = [city text]; // City last seen, cls from insert url
    NSString *sls = [stateLabel text]; // State last seen, sls from insert url
    NSString *jls = [jurisdiction text]; // Jursidiction last seen, jls from insert url
    NSString *countystring = [county text];
    NSString *mdate = [dateLabel text]; // Missing Date, mdate from insert url
    NSString *mtime = [timeLabel text]; // Missing Time, mtime from insert url
    NSString *dob = [dobLabel text]; // Date of Birth, dob from insert url
    dob = [dob stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"-"];
    NSString *race = [ethnicityLabel text];
    NSString *heightstringft = [heightft text];
    NSString *heightstringin = [heightin text];
    NSString *gender = [genderLabel text];
    NSString *weightstring = [weight text];
    NSString *hair = [hairColorLabel text];
    NSString *eye = [eyeColorLabel text];
    NSString *cloths = [clothingdescription text];
    NSString *baseurl = @"http://my.domain.tld/php/newCase1Insert.php?cn=";
    NSString *buildurl = [baseurl stringByAppendingFormat:casenumber];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&fn="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:fn];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&ln="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:ln];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&age="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:age];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&als="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:als];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&cls="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:cls];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&sls="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:sls];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&jls="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:jls];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&mdate="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:mdate];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&mtime="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:mtime];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&dob="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:dob];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&race="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:race];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&height="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:heightstringft];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:heightstringin];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&gender="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:gender];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&weight="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:weightstring];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&hair="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:hair];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&eye="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:eye];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&cloths="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:cloths];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingString:@"&county="];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByAppendingFormat:countystring];
    buildurl = [buildurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%%20"];
    NSLog(buildurl);
    inserturl1 = buildurl;
```

Can anybody help me figure out why it's not running the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue I found. I wasn't encoding my URL Correctly. I had to re-encode my URL with NSUTF8String encoding. [My co-worker found the fix here.](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUrl)

Here is how you do it:

```
NSString  *myURL = // some URL
NSString  *fixedURL = [myURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // or any other encoding
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString :fixedURL];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this code to get error description:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Also, take into account that remote server may read HTTP headers to adopt (or block) your request.

Comment: all that the error tells me is `bad URL`, but I can copy the url it's sending into a browser and it submits it.